# How to get an information string, int from SQL, but the information must not be initialized?

Tags: java, sql, string

I want to get some informations in my SQL base, but i don't know how to. I have already used this following code :

```
String pseudo = null;

String query = "select * from UsersInfos where Pseudo=?"
PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(query);

statement.setString(1, pseudo);

ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();

while (rs.next()) {

  pseudo = rs.getString("Pseudo");

}

System.out.println(pseudo);
```

But it returns me null of

```
System.out.println(pseudo);
```

I want to get some informations, not set them, well can some one helps me please ?

Comment: can you tell us the structure of table.Also,it doesnt make sense as why you want to print "pseudo" when you are passing "pseudo" in where condition

Comment: See down with the following picture

Answer (score 1):

Your result set is coming back empty.  In other words, the assignment `pseudo = rs.getString("Pseudo")` never took place.

The reason the result set is empty (i.e. contains no records) is due to the `WHERE` clause:

```
select * from UsersInfos where Pseudo=null
```

The comparison of any value in the `Pseudo` column to null will be either null or false (depending on your particular RDBMS).  This means that no records will match.